# SharePoint - create folder inside an existing folder (at server)

Tags: android, sharepoint

I want to add a folder at a location (inside a folder, not list or library!). I have tried to use the "Add Folder" REST API as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FolderCollectionAdd).

I'm setting the `X-RequestDigest` in the header from the what I receive from the `myweb.com/_api/contextinfo`.

I'm unsure what to replace `<app web url>` and `<host web url>` with.

I've replaced `<app web url>` with the folder location (at server) and `<host web url>` with my server URL but he response I get is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-2130575252, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."
        }
    }
}
```

I'm developing an app for Android and I figure I can only use the SOAP or REST API, and I'm using the later. Any help? :(

### Update:

I've replaced `<app web url>` with `myweb.com/me/username/` and `<host web url>` with `myweb.com` and the response I get is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "There is no app context to execute this request."
        }
    }
}
```

From a friend's help I came to know I need to `OAuth` before I could create a folder. Have to say, SharePoint's documentation is really unconvincing. Why make simple things too difficult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to create a folder without `OAuth`. The details of the request I used are as below:

1. POST request to URL `https://example.com/me/username/_api/web/folders?$expand=Properties`,
2. POST body `{ '__metadata':{ 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl':'/me/username/Documents/folderName' }`,
3. headers (key : value):

   ```
   'Accept' : 'application/json;odata=verbose'
   'X-RequestDigest' : *some value here*
   'content-type' : 'application/json;odata=verbose'
   ```